# How can I add a custom rake task to my engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines, rake-task

I am writing an engine and I want to include a task in it.
I wrote my file .rake, bus it isn't listed with rake --task. If I try to run int anyway I get:

> ❯ rake what2find:index
> rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'what2find:index' (See the
> list of available tasks with `rake -T -A`)
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I don't understand why.

lib/tasks/what2find/index.rake

```
namespace :what2find do
  desc "Indexes the configured entities"
  task :index => :environment do
    include What2find
    # Task logic
  end
end
```

Rakefile:

```
begin
  require 'bundler/setup'
rescue LoadError
  puts 'You must `gem install bundler` and `bundle install` to run rake tasks'
end

require 'rdoc/task'

RDoc::Task.new(:rdoc) do |rdoc|
  rdoc.rdoc_dir = 'rdoc'
  rdoc.title    = 'What2find'
  rdoc.options << '--line-numbers'
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('README.md')
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('lib/**/*.rb')
end

APP_RAKEFILE = File.expand_path("test/dummy/Rakefile", __dir__)
load 'rails/tasks/engine.rake'

load 'rails/tasks/statistics.rake'
# load 'lib/tasks/what2find_tasks.rake'

require 'bundler/gem_tasks'

require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.pattern = 'test/**/*_test.rb'
  t.verbose = false
end

task default: :test
```

My gem's directory structure is:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   └── what2find_manifest.js
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   └── what2find
│   │   └── stylesheets
│   │       └── what2find
│   │           └── application.css
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── what2find
│   │       └── application_controller.rb
│   ├── helpers
│   │   └── what2find
│   │       └── application_helper.rb
│   ├── jobs
│   │   └── what2find
│   │       └── application_job.rb
│   ├── mailers
│   │   └── what2find
│   │       └── application_mailer.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── index.rb
│   │   └── what2find
│   │       └── application_record.rb
│   └── views
│       └── layouts
│           └── what2find
│               └── application.html.erb
├── bin
│   └── rails
├── config
│   ├── initializers
│   │   └── what2find.rb.dist
│   └── routes.rb
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── lib
│   ├── tasks
│   │   ├── test.rake
│   │   ├── what2find
│   │   │   └── index.rake
│   │   ├── what2find.rake
│   │   └── what2find_tasks.rake
│   ├── what2find
│   │   ├── engine.rb
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── what2find.rb
├── MIT-LICENSE
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
├── test
│   ├── dummy
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── assets
│   │   │   │   ├── config
│   │   │   │   │   └── manifest.js
│   │   │   │   ├── images
│   │   │   │   └── stylesheets
│   │   │   │       └── application.css
│   │   │   ├── channels
│   │   │   │   └── application_cable
│   │   │   │       ├── channel.rb
│   │   │   │       └── connection.rb
│   │   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   │   ├── application_controller.rb
│   │   │   │   └── concerns
│   │   │   ├── helpers
│   │   │   │   └── application_helper.rb
│   │   │   ├── javascript
│   │   │   │   └── packs
│   │   │   │       └── application.js
│   │   │   ├── jobs
│   │   │   │   └── application_job.rb
│   │   │   ├── mailers
│   │   │   │   └── application_mailer.rb
│   │   │   ├── models
│   │   │   │   ├── application_record.rb
│   │   │   │   └── concerns
│   │   │   └── views
│   │   │       └── layouts
│   │   │           ├── application.html.erb
│   │   │           ├── mailer.html.erb
│   │   │           └── mailer.text.erb
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   │   ├── rails
│   │   │   ├── rake
│   │   │   └── setup
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   ├── application.rb
│   │   │   ├── boot.rb
│   │   │   ├── cable.yml
│   │   │   ├── database.yml
│   │   │   ├── environment.rb
│   │   │   ├── environments
│   │   │   │   ├── development.rb
│   │   │   │   ├── production.rb
│   │   │   │   └── test.rb
│   │   │   ├── initializers
│   │   │   │   ├── application_controller_renderer.rb
│   │   │   │   ├── assets.rb
│   │   │   │   ├── backtrace_silencers.rb
│   │   │   │   ├── content_security_policy.rb
│   │   │   │   ├── cookies_serializer.rb
│   │   │   │   ├── filter_parameter_logging.rb
│   │   │   │   ├── inflections.rb
│   │   │   │   ├── mime_types.rb
│   │   │   │   └── wrap_parameters.rb
│   │   │   ├── locales
│   │   │   │   └── en.yml
│   │   │   ├── puma.rb
│   │   │   ├── routes.rb
│   │   │   ├── spring.rb
│   │   │   └── storage.yml
│   │   ├── config.ru
│   │   ├── db
│   │   │   └── test.sqlite3
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── assets
│   │   ├── log
│   │   │   ├── development.log
│   │   │   └── test.log
│   │   ├── public
│   │   │   ├── 404.html
│   │   │   ├── 422.html
│   │   │   ├── 500.html
│   │   │   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   │   │   ├── apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
│   │   │   └── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── Rakefile
│   │   ├── storage
│   │   └── tmp
│   │       ├── cache
│   │       │   └── assets
│   │       ├── development_secret.txt
│   │       ├── pids
│   │       └── storage
│   ├── integration
│   │   └── navigation_test.rb
│   ├── test_helper.rb
│   └── what2find_test.rb
└── what2find.gemspec
```

And my application's directory:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   └── manifest.js
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── stylesheets
│   │       └── application.css
│   ├── channels
│   │   └── application_cable
│   │       ├── channel.rb
│   │       └── connection.rb
│   ├── connectors
│   │   ├── abstract_connector.rb
│   │   ├── claro_video.rb
│   │   ├── environment_variables.rb
│   │   ├── movistar_play.rb
│   │   └── netflix.rb
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── application_controller.rb
│   │   ├── concerns
│   │   └── content_controller.rb
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── application_helper.rb
│   │   ├── connectors_helper.rb
│   │   └── movistar_helper.rb
│   ├── javascript
│   │   ├── channels
│   │   │   ├── consumer.js
│   │   │   └── index.js
│   │   └── packs
│   │       └── application.js
│   ├── jobs
│   │   └── application_job.rb
│   ├── mailers
│   │   └── application_mailer.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── concerns
│   │   └── content.rb
│   └── views
│       └── layouts
│           ├── application.html.erb
│           ├── mailer.html.erb
│           └── mailer.text.erb
├── babel.config.js
├── bin
│   ├── bundle
│   ├── rails
│   ├── rake
│   ├── setup
│   ├── spring
│   ├── webpack
│   ├── webpack-dev-server
│   └── yarn
├── config
│   ├── application.rb
│   ├── boot.rb
│   ├── cable.yml
│   ├── credentials.yml.enc
│   ├── environment.rb
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── development.rb
│   │   ├── production.rb
│   │   └── test.rb
│   ├── initializers
│   │   ├── application_controller_renderer.rb
│   │   ├── assets.rb
│   │   ├── backtrace_silencers.rb
│   │   ├── content_security_policy.rb
│   │   ├── cookies_serializer.rb
│   │   ├── filter_parameter_logging.rb
│   │   ├── inflections.rb
│   │   ├── mime_types.rb
│   │   ├── what2find.rb
│   │   └── wrap_parameters.rb
│   ├── locales
│   │   └── en.yml
│   ├── master.key
│   ├── mongoid.yml
│   ├── puma.rb
│   ├── routes.rb
│   ├── spring.rb
│   └── webpacker.yml
├── config.ru
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── lib
│   ├── assets
│   ├── request.rb
│   └── tasks
│       └── content.rake
├── log
│   └── development.log
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 422.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   ├── apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── robots.txt
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
├── test
│   ├── application_system_test_case.rb
│   ├── channels
│   │   └── application_cable
│   │       └── connection_test.rb
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   └── files
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── integration
│   ├── mailers
│   ├── models
│   ├── system
│   └── test_helper.rb
├── vendor
└── yarn.lock
```

Someone can say me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Will [this](https://til.codes/load-rake-files-and-run-tasks-from-other-files/) help you?

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. Unfortunately it don't solve totally my problem. I tried the post suggerences and now I get the task listed if i run task -T from my engine folder. but if I want to run the task from my application the task isn't listed with any of the raised options.

Comment: Could you post your directory structure here?

Comment: Sure! I'll update in the question.